# One if or multiple where?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case, query-optimization

Let's say, I want to set a value to multiple rows depending on the value of another cell. So, I can make this in 2 ways:

1. Select all items and set different values using `IF`:

```
Update `table` set `a` = 
    if (
        `b`>=100,  
        if (`b`>=1000, ... , 'Less than thousand') , 
        'Less than hundred'
    ) 
where `someid`='1'
```

2. Or do several updates:

```
Update `table` set `a` = 'Less than hundred'  where `someid`='1' and `b`<100;
Update `table` set `a` = 'Less than thousand' where `someid`='1' and `b`<1000 and `b`>=100;
...
```

Which one will be better practice in performance?

Comment: Why don't you test both version and measure the results?

Comment: @Shadow maybe someone can answer without testing

Comment: No, someone can make an educated guess. You, however, can get the definite answer by testing. The results can greatly be influenced by how many records match the `someid='1' ` criterion. But only you know the answer to that.

Comment: The first one may use `INDEX(someid)`; the second one _may_ be better because it can use `INDEX(someid, b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend running a single query, and using `CASE` insteaf of `IF` to make the syntax easier to follow.

Running multiple queries mean multiple table scans, whereas this query does just one scan.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET a = CASE
    WHEN b < 100 THEN 'Less than an hundred'
    WHEN b < 1000 THEN 'Less than an thousand'
    ...
END
```

With an index on `b`, this should be very efficient.

Comment: Index on `b` will not help since `b` is buried inside that expression.